# How can I get the content of a 422 response in tests?

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

I want to test 422 response body, as in my case it should contain validation errors,
so basically my tests looks like this

```
    public function testReturnsBadRequest(): void
    {
        $response = static::createClient()->request(
            'POST',
            'api/v1/products/id',
            [
                'headers' => [
                    'accept' => ['application/json'],
                    'content-type' => 'application/json',
                ],
                'body' => json_encode(['shopId' => 'invalid',])
            ]
        );
        self::assertResponseStatusCodeSame(422);


        /** @var array{data: array<string, mixed>} $product */
        $errors = json_decode($response->getContent(), true);
        self::assertArrayHasKey('errors', $errors);
  }
```

and everything works fine till the moment I'm trying to get content when I'm calling `$response->getContent()` my test fails with error

> Symfony\Component\HttpClient\Exception\ClientException: HTTP 422 returned for "http://localhost/api/v1/products/id".

How can I get response body instead of thrown exception?

Answer (score 0):

You have to either:

- Call `$respone->getContent(false)`, so [it doesn't throw exceptions on non-successful responses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68303486/why-cant-i-access-the-response-content-when-the-symfony-http-client-encounters/68303677#68303677)
- Add a call to `$this->expectException(ClientException::class)` before you call `$response->getContent()`:

  ```php
  $this->expectException(ClientException::class);
  $errors = json_decode($response->getContent(), true);
  ```